# How are metric TSP and Eulerian cycle equivalent?

Tags: traveling-salesman, eulerian-paths

In paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.00227.pdf it is stated that

> In the metric TSP problem, which we study here, the distances satisfy the triangle inequality. Therefore the problem is equivalent to finding a closed Eulerian connected walk of minimum cost.

They don't seem to be equivalent at all, since for a complete graph of size 5, with all edge costs 1, a metric TSP solution would be of cost (and length) 5, whereas an Eulerian cycle would be of cost (and length) 10. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48549/5038

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has also been asked on CSTheory.